# RxJS behavior subject and Angular ngModel binding with ngFor

Tags: angular, rxjs

Not sure how to ask this, so if anyone can clear it up please do.
If I put an angular component on a page twice and get the data from a behavior subject, everything works fine, until I bind to an input using ngModel. It appears as though I don't understand what's happening. I have attached a plunker. When you update the input, it updates everywhere. I'm not sure I'm being clear, but the plunker hopefully makes it obvious.

http://plnkr.co/edit/OQFEGVJAJF5kHhWoTOpm?p=preview

**app component:**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/common';

import { TodoComponent } from 'app/todo.component';
import { TodoService } from 'app/todo.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'todo-app',
  template: `

    <h3>Component 1</h3>
    <todo-component></todo-component>

    <br /><br />

    <h3>Component 2</h3>
    <todo-component></todo-component>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() { }
}
```

**the component:**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TodoService } from 'app/todo.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'todo-component',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let t of test | async">
      <div>test: {{t.prop}}</div>
      <div>test: <input [(ngModel)]="t.prop"></div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class TodoComponent {
  private test: any;

  constructor(private todoService: TodoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.test = this.todoService.test;
  }
}
```

**the service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';    
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {
  private initialTestState = [{prop: 'val'}];
  private test$: BehaviorSubject<[]>;
  private test: Observable<[]>;

  constructor() {
    this.test$ = new BehaviorSubject<[]>(this.initialTestState);
  }

  get test() {
    return this.test$.asObservable();
  }

}
```

[image: Why!]

Comment: Did you expect something different? They all share a reference to the same mutable object.

Answer (score 0):

You should return different object references

```js
  get test() {
    let obj = [{prop: 'val'}];
    return new BehaviorSubject<[]>(obj);
  }
```

subscribe to the service and use `index` for different objects

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'todo-component',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let t of test; let i = index; ">
      <div>test: {{test[i].prop}}</div>
      <div>test: <input [(ngModel)]="test[i].prop"></div>
    </div>
  `
})

export class TodoComponent {
  private test: any;

  constructor(private todoService: TodoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.todoService.test.subscribe(o => this.test = o);

  }
}
```

Comment: Will this automatically unsubscribe if the TodoComponent is destroyed?